# CA1062 is thrown after updating to !! parameter null checking

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-6.0, c#-10.0, c#-11.0

According to CA1062 null checks are required in externally visible methods like this:

```
public static double GetLongitude(this Location location)
{
    if(location is null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(location));
    }

    return location.Longitude;
}
```

I have now updated to .net 6.0 and tried to use the parameter null check "!!":

```
public static double GetLongitude(this Location location!!) => location.Longitude;
```

But this thrown CA1062 again.

Hope you guys can help me :-)

Comment: There's no such operator in C# 10

Comment: That used to work if you were compiling with `<LangVersion>preview</LangVersion>` but they removed the `!!` language feature recently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no such operator in C# 10/.NET 6. [Parameter null checking](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/proposals/param-nullchecking.md) is a proposal for the upcoming C# 11 that [was eventually postponed](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2022/LDM-2022-04-06.md#parameter-null-checking) due to developer objections in April 2022.